# List of functions defined via an iterator contains a bunch of copies of the same function

Tags: python, pointers, iterator

I want to create a list of functions, each defined on the set {0,1,2}, by setting their values to those found in a list of values. To check what I did, I then print the values of my functions. Here are two attempts:

```
values_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

function_list = []
function_list.append((lambda x: values_list[0][x]))
function_list.append((lambda x: values_list[1][x]))
print('Values of 1st function:',function_list[0](0),function_list[0](1),function_list[0](2))
print('Values of 1st function:',function_list[1](0),function_list[1](1),function_list[1](2))

function_list1 = []
for i in range(2):
    function_list1.append((lambda x: values_list[i][x]))
print('Values of 1st function:',function_list1[0](0),function_list1[0](1),function_list1[0](2))
print('Values of 2nd function:',function_list1[1](0),function_list1[1](1),function_list1[1](2))
```

The first attempt works fine, of course, but in the second attempt, both functions in the list are identical. They both give back the second set of values.

Ok, so I guess the reason is, that the iterator that I used in the definition stopped at the second set of values. But in practice I will have huge lists of function values, of varying length, and I can't type a line for each function in my list, as in my first attempt. What could I do to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fix this line to:

```
function_list1.append((lambda x,y=i: values_list[y][x]))
```